# Task bar Icon getting referred from Desktop shortcut

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, icons, application-icon

I have a `WPF` project and in which the **Application Icon is taken from a specific path** using a converter and please find the sample code block.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
Icon="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IconToImageConverter}}"
```

**Converter class:**

```
public class IconToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri(TheIconPath)); 
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}
```

We can replace the icon any time in the specific path and it will be reflected in the Taskbar while we run the application next time from the **bin folder or Visual studio.**

We have an installer for this application which creates the Desktop shortcut Icon for the application. Now it seems like the **taskbar icon is only taken from the Desktop shortcut icon** and it never changes based on the Icon placed on the specific path.

> My requirement is that I need the icon to be referred from the specific path as it behaved on the bin or visual studio.

Comment: Your observation is likely to be a result of icon being cached. You can theoretically [clear cache](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3243317/1997232), but I think recreating shortcut should work too.