# WPF app's icon not updated when the exe file is updated

Tags: wpf, nsis

I built a WPF desktop app (let's call this `my_app.exe`) and deployed using NSIS script to create an installer. When the users installed the app, the my_app.exe is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\app_folder`. So, whenever I want to update the app with newer version, I create a new installer. When users reinstall, old `my_app.exe` is replaced with new exe file. The issue I'm encountering is, even though I changed the icon of the app, the exe icon doesn't change (even though I can see the content of the app changed). Is there a way to make the icon updated?

Comment: When you say "the exe icon doesn't change", do you mean a shortcut on the desktop? Or in File Explorer? Or when the app is running? Or maybe all of the above?

Comment: @JimFoye It's all of the above (shortcut, icon in file explorer, running app icon)

Answer (score 0):

Explorer and the shell caches the icons. You can try to [force a refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3243317) or just wait until Windows figures it out on its own.

You can use a tool like [Resource Hacker](https://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to actually verify that the .exe contains the icon you think it does.